# How to use the responsive images feature from WP 4.4 in your themes

Tags: theme-development, responsive, images

I don't really understand how I can use the new responsive images feature that WordPress provides in my themes.

Example:

In my theme, I add a header-image. I therefore use the custom-header-image from customizer OR the post-thumbnail:

```
<figure id="header-image" class="uk-margin-remove">
<?php if ( ( is_single() || ! is_home() ) && has_post_thumbnail() ) : ?>
    <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
<?php else: ?>
    ???
<?php endif; ?>
</figure>
```

So in the first case, the output is this:

```
<img src="http://xxx.dev/wp-content/uploads/x.jpg" srcset="http://xxx.dev/wp-content/uploads/x-300x70.jpg 300w, http://xxx.dev/wp-content/uploads/x-768x180.jpg 768w, http://xxx.dev/wp-content/uploads/x-1024x241.jpg 1024w" sizes="(max-width: 300px) 100vw, 300px" alt="">
```

which is perfectly fine. But If I want to display an image by attachment ID, no matter which function I use, I don't get the output I expect.

Example:

In the code above you see "???". In that place, I tried some things. For example this:

```
<?php echo wp_get_attachment_image( get_custom_header()->attachment_id, 'full' ); ?>
```

Which only results in one size (see sizes attribute):

```
<img src="http://xxx.dev/wp-content/uploads/Delft_IMG_6275-e1453192498922.jpg" class="attachment-full size-full" alt="Delft_IMG_6275" srcset="http://xxx.dev/wp-content/uploads/Delft_IMG_6275-e1453192498922.jpg 1920w, http://xxx.dev/wp-content/uploads/Delft_IMG_6275-e1453192498922-300x70.jpg 300w, http://xxx.dev/wp-content/uploads/Delft_IMG_6275-e1453192498922-768x180.jpg 768w, http://xxx.dev/wp-content/uploads/Delft_IMG_6275-e1453192498922-1024x241.jpg 1024w" sizes="(max-width: 1920px) 100vw, 1920px" height="451" width="1920">
```

So, what's the proper way of displaying images in the theme so that it outputs a similar result as `the_post_thumbnail()`?

Comment: You need to have a selection of image sizes defined that are the same aspect ratio as the size you use in your code. Then WP will construct a Srcset attribute using them all.

Comment: How to achieve that automatically?

Comment: I'm on a deadline at the moment but will try an answer afterwards. Do you create any extra image sizes in your theme, or do you just use the built-in sizes available through the admin media options page?

Comment: For now I just use the default ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following our exchange in the comments I've reread your question and have a pretty straightforward answer:

It looks like it's working fine.

You are worried about the `sizes` attribute in your second example, but it's the `srcset` attribute that you should look at and it *is* showing all of your image sizes:

```
<img 

src="http://xxx.dev/wp-content/uploads/Delft_IMG_6275-e1453192498922.jpg" 

class="attachment-full size-full" alt="Delft_IMG_6275" 

srcset="http://xxx.dev/wp-content/uploads/Delft_IMG_6275-e1453192498922.jpg 1920w,
http://xxx.dev/wp-content/uploads/Delft_IMG_6275-e1453192498922-300x70.jpg 300w,
http://xxx.dev/wp-content/uploads/Delft_IMG_6275-e1453192498922-768x180.jpg 768w,
http://xxx.dev/wp-content/uploads/Delft_IMG_6275-e1453192498922-1024x241.jpg 1024w"

sizes="(max-width: 1920px) 100vw, 1920px"

height="451" width="1920">
```

Your browser reads the attributes like this:

1 - Look at the `sizes` attribute and find the first match for the current viewport width. In this case, if the viewport is anything up to `1920px` wide, then use the `100vw` value, converted to `px`, otherwise use `1920px`.

2 - Look at the `srcset` attribute and choose an image that fits the value from (1).

On a nice big screen with a full width window the browser chooses the `sizes` value of `1920px`.  This points the browser to the image marked with `1920w` in the srcset attribute, with the URL of your full size image.

On a portrait iPad, where the viewport is `768px` wide, the value obtained in (1) will be `100vw` which for this viewport is `768px`.  Looking in the `srcset` for `768w` we get the URL to the `medium_large` image size (a new default size in WP4.4 which doesn't show in the admin interface).

When there's no exact match for the viewport width, the browser should choose the next size up.

Now, there are circumstances where you might want to supply a longer list of images which you can add using `add_image_size()` in your theme.  WP will build a `srcset` attribute using all the images that match the aspect ratio of the image size you choose to display.

There are also circumstances where you want a custom `sizes` attribute and you can filter the attribute for that, but as your question stands I don't think that's what you're after.

Comment: Hm... But when I use the firefox dev tools to resize the website to max 300px wide and then reload the page, the browser still puts the original 1920px wide image inside the src="".

Comment: Yes.  That's correct.  The src attribute isn't modified dynamically, it's there for backwards compatibility with browsers that don't understand srcset.  Try right-clicking the image and opening in a new window, or inspecting the image in dev tools.  You should see that the browser is using the 300px wide image file.

Comment: Cool - No problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an [array](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_image/) as size:

```
wp_get_attachment_image( get_custom_header()->attachment_id, array('700', '600'));
```

**EDIT:**

@downvoter  say why you are downvoting. I agree I was in a way wrong, but you could have said "Yes you can use an array to size the image, BUT, it will only default to the nearest size to a defined image size.

Defined images are either set in the media section of SETTINGS->MEDIA in the backend admin, these will be "thumbnail, "medium' and "full" OR by custom use and you can use `add_image_size('name-you want-use', 340, 230, true);` in your functions file ETC...ETC..

Comment: No offense but is this just a guess? I was looking for a best practice. I already played around with the new functions but nothing seemed to be really good.

Comment: What do you mean "is this just a guess?" and no offence taken.

Comment: I think @SVARTBERG means that it's hard to see how your answer addresses the question.  Maybe you could expand it and explain why using an array based image size solves the original problem.

Comment: @AndyMacaulay-Brook .... Yes, point taken.. I have over the last few days come to realise that my measly little bit of knowledge of WordPress is of no use here at WPSE. I'll leave it to you 4 with the supperior knowledge, years of experience and understanding of exactly what, how and when to answer questions here.

Comment: @AndyMacaulay-Brook. PS, your answer makes perfect sense, but wording like that not only being Thai, but a human, is WAY out of my league, so best leave it.

Comment: Your contributions are important for WPSE and visitors to the site. There can be many reasons for a downvote and we should try to not take it personally. I really hope you reconsider  leaving the site.  @Malisa

Comment: Yeah don't go! This is a learning experience, I started out like you and learned probably most of my WordPress knowledge by contributing on here.

Comment: Everyone's contribution helps.  I think we've all received down votes and requests to expand or improve upon the answers we've provided.

Answer (score 0):

On the one hand, there is nothing you should do, on the other, wordpress do not actually create responsive images.

Wordpress will create a `srcset` attributes whenever you use the image related APIs based on the registered image sizes, with all the images that match the aspect ratio. What you need to do is to have the relevant image sizes registered in order for wordpress to be able to generate the images, and use them in a `srcset`.

In your "failed" example full images will never be responsive since wordpress will not generate images that are bigger then the original image (and in any case it is tricky to code an image generation for size that change from one image to another).

What you need to do in your theme is to decided which sizes you want to support and define them first. for example if you want a 150x150 thumbnail to be served also to x2 retina then you will need to register both a 150x150 size and 300x300 size. If on mobile you allocate a 50x50 space for the thumbnail, then you will also need to register also a 50x50 and 100x100 (for retina) sizes, not sure this is wise in practice but that is the theory of it.

Rant: Calling what wordpress core does a feature is an insult to intelligence. It is a sweetener to help you avoid doing many API call, but it does not help you with actually designing what size you actually need, and still keep it tedious to configure wordpress to use them.